# Is it legal C to use an address that has not been allocated?

Tags: c

I don't know much about how memory allocation actually works, but what would be the problem with this:

```
int main(){
    int a=1;
    int *p = &a;
    p++;
    *p = 2;
    printf("%d", *p);

    return 0;  

}
```

Comment: Well when it comes down it, what would be the problem in changing any random 4 or 8 bytes anywhere in a program?  What could go wrong?

Comment: The behavior of such code is undefined. Anything can happen, most probably a part of your stack will be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it yields undefined behavior, often leading to a memory access violation.

In your example, however, it might work fine since variable `p` is possibly located immediately after variable `a` in the stack (subjected to the compiler that you are using), so by incrementing the value of variable `p` you are essentially setting it to point to itself.

Now, if `sizeof(p) == sizeof(*p)`, i.e., if `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)`, which happens to be the case on many compilers (where both are equal 4), then when you write a value into the address pointed by `p`, you are setting both `p` and `*p` to that value.

Please note that any subsequent attempt to write a value into the address pointed by `p`, will be equivalent to writing a value into address 2 in the memory space of your program, and this time it **will** most likely lead to a memory access violation.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. It is not legal to use unallocated memory location to read or write. It invokes **undefined behavior**

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting memory you did not allocate by yourself. This infers undefined behavior, which is by definition not good and thus "not legal".

Answer (score 0):

One should never try to access a memory which is not defined/allocated by yourself as this can lead to something unpredictable.
This would not give syntax error but runtime errors can be generated.
So always make sure before accessing a memory that it has been allocated by you only.